# Conditional import - how to discard records?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I want to import a csv file using SQLLDR, but I only want specific records. I have solved this with `"WHEN record_type = 1"` in my control file.

This works but the log file is getting flooded by *"Record xxx: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses."* The input files contain millions of records but only a few percent satisfy the condition, so I end up with a log file with the same size as the input file :)

Am I doing this incorrectly?
Is there another way to discard/filter records when using SQLLDR?

Example Data:

```
record_type;a;b;c
24;a1;b1;c1
17;a2;b2;c2
22;an;bn;cn
1;a1;b1;c1
1;a2;b2;c2
1;an;bn;cn
```

Control file

```
load data
truncate
into table my_table_t
WHEN record_type = 1
(...
)
```

Comment: You could try using EXTERNAL TABLES rather than SQL*Loader.  Or alternatively, if the target rows are only a small fraction of the file, you could use a UNIX pattern matching command to build a small file containing just your target records.

Comment: @ChristianPalmer, the target rows are only a fraction of the file so I investigate the unix filtering as well. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: something like this UNIX> grep -e "^1;" test_file.dat > output_file.dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is right IMO.

SQL*Loader is logging to the finest level of the loading details for you. You can opt out from few of the things.

Yo can disable the `DISCARD` records logging by adding
`SILENT=(DISCARDS)` to your `SQL*Loader`

You can refer the [DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this myself. But I'm removing my own answer. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the log you can send these log to `/dev/null` if you using Linux/Unix and `NUL` on Windows.

### Example

Data File.

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ cat sample.txt 
record_type;a;b;c
24;a1;b1;c1
17;a2;b2;c2
22;an;bn;cn
1;a1;b1;c1
1;a2;b2;c2
1;an;bn;cn
```

Control file.

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ cat control.ctl 
load data
 infile 'sample.txt'
 insert
 into table table_1  when record_type = '1'
 fields terminated by ";"
 (record_type, a, b, c)
```

Lets try to load records.

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ sqlldr jay/password@orapdb1 control=control.ctl data=sample.txt log=/dev/null

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Fri Feb 10 16:05:10 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 7

Table TABLE_1:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  /dev/null
for more information about the load.
```

There was no log file.

Now we got the only selected records.

```
SQL> select * from table_1;

RECORD_TYPE A            B            C
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
      1 a1           b1           c1
      1 a2           b2           c2
      1 an           bn           cn
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the log file, so I can't discard it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Using the external table, you can then use simple SQL to load your table...

```
insert into my_table_t( record_type, a, b, c )
select record_type, a, b, c 
from my_external_table
where record_type != 1
```

Comment: I can not use external tables in this particular case.

Comment: @Ronnis. Can you elaborate as to why you cannot use an external table?